# Pagination issue

Tags: php, pagination

I'm currently using the following snippet for an improvised pagination system. Unfortunately, I've run into a bit of a roadblock. The variable `$result->info['pages']` is returned by a remote API and is the number of pages available. The variable `$result->info['page']` is the currently visible page. The links appear as expected an in the right place, but they act as if the page is ALWAYS 1 (The '1' link always shows as plaintext, everything else always shows as a link). However, if I echo the `$result->info['page']`, it shows the correct page number, and the information displayed is correct. Thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong?

```
<?php if ($result->info['pages'] > '1') {
    if ($result->info['page'] != '1') {
        echo '<a onClick="location.replace(\'?page=' . --$result->info['page'] . '\');">Prev</a> ';
    } else {
        echo 'Prev ';
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $result->info['pages']; $i++) {
        if ($i == $result->info['page']) {
            echo $i . ' ';
        } else {
            echo '<a onClick="location.replace(\'?page=' . $i .'\');">' . $i . '</a> ';
        }
    }
    if ($result->info['page'] != $result->info['pages']) {
        echo '<a onClick="location.replace(\'?page=' . ++$result->info['page'] . '\');">Next</a>';
    } else {
        echo 'Next';
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($result->info['pages'], $result->info['page']);`

Comment: why use js when you could just use a regular html link?

Comment: @zerkms both variables show exactly what they should... on page 1, `$result->info['pages']` shows 2 and `$result->info['page']` shows 1. on page 2, `$result->info['pages']` shows 2 and `$result->info['page']` shows 2.

Comment: @Dagon thanks for the tip on backticks... and because originally i was trying to handle the pagination through ajax, took a step back and decided not to for now, but never got out of the javascript mindset. Does that matter?

Comment: @zerkms http://ideone.com/iO7D0 --- but if you set `$result->info['page']` to 2, you don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to modify `--$result->info['page']`, just replace it with `($result->info['page'] - 1)` and everything will go well

http://ideone.com/WiGh4

```
<?php

$result = new stdClass();
$result->info = array(
    'pages' => 2,
    'page' => 2
);

if ($result->info['pages'] > '1') {
    if ($result->info['page'] != '1') {
        echo '<a onClick="location.replace(\'?page=' . ($result->info['page'] - 1) . '\');">Prev</a> ';
    } else {
        echo 'Prev ';
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $result->info['pages']; $i++) {
        if ($i == $result->info['page']) {
            echo $i . ' ';
        } else {
            echo '<a onClick="location.replace(\'?page=' . $i .'\');">' . $i . '</a> ';
        }
    }
    if ($result->info['page'] != $result->info['pages']) {
        echo '<a onClick="location.replace(\'?page=' . ($result->info['page'] + 1) . '\');">Next</a>';
    } else {
        echo 'Next';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: That causes them to display properly, but if you click on the link it doesn't do anything... because you're linking to the already active page.

Comment: Turns out you were right... it worked if there were only two pages, add more than that and next works, but prev doesn't. Can you explain to me the difference between `--$var` and `($var - 1)`?

Comment: @Ghost1227: `($var - 1)` - returns the result and lefts `$var` value unchanged, while `--$var` modifies the original value. So after `--$page` you got your page changed to one back (which is just wrong)

Comment: @Ghost1227: `++` modifies value as well. I changed it here in answer but forgot to fix on ideone

Comment: But it seems to be working with `++`... Next question. Any idea how to do this without actually RELOADING the page on change?

Comment: @Ghost1227: it works with `++` because you don't care of the value after that. To do "what" without reloading?

Comment: Load the data inline without actually passing it as a $_GET variable and reloading the whole page. It's not horrible to do in some situations, but in others it's really ugly looking.

Comment: I figured ajax or similar was the solution, but my ajax skills are somewhat lacking. Figured since those involved in this conversation already know what I'm doing, it was a good place to ask.

Comment: @Ghost1227: start with **basic** jquery ajax examples and come back with new question when you have some particular issue